# Callback method for frame Tkinter.Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on desktop application in Python 2.7 Tkinter. My app has several screens and I've implemented them using single frame for each screen and a single main controller. The controller class has the following method for bringing the frame on top.

```
def show_frame(self, pageName):
    """
    Show a frame for the given page name.
    """
    frame = self.frames[pageName]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Where self.frames has the `initialised` frame objects with `pageName` as keys.

Is there any callback method on Tkinter.Frame which I can implement, so that if there is any change on one screen, it can be updated on another whenever that screen is displayed?

Reference for above code snippet: 
[How to change and show a new window in Tkinter](https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized, I can write a callback myself and call it wherever I call `tkraise`, but have a check in place for the classes that do not implement the callback method.

```
def show_frame(self, pageName):
    """
    Show a frame for the given page name.
    """
    frame = self.frames[pageName]
    frame.tkraise()

    # only call 'on_tkraise' method, if the object's class has implemented it
    # can be used for updating UI
    if hasattr(frame, 'on_tkraise') and callable(getattr(frame, 'on_tkraise')) :
        frame.on_tkraise()
```